# Let $A$ be an exponential random variable with mean $5$. What is the variance of $10A-3$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance

> Let $A$ be an exponential random variable with mean $5$, $λ = 1/5$.
>   What is the variance of $10A-3$?

Is my work correct?
$$\text{Var}(10A-3) = 100\text{Var}(A) = 100 \left(\frac{1}{(1/5)^2}\right) = 2500$$

Comment: oh and it was exponential distribution

Comment: Yes, it is right, if by parameter $\lambda$ you mean density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ (the usual convention but sadly not universal).

Comment: Great, thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: wow that looks much better, I will learn to do the formatting next time. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment: yes, correct. Approximate verification (two to three significant digits) by simulation in R.

```
 a = rexp(10^6, 1/5);  mean(a);  var(a)
 ## 4.998641  # approx 5
 ## 25.02616  # approx 25
 b = 10*a - 3;  mean(b);  var(b)
 ## 46.98641  # approx 47
 ## 2502.616  # approx 2500
```